# Workaround for Scala RDD not being covariant

Tags: scala, types, covariance, apache-spark

I'm trying to write a function to operate on RDD[Seq[String]] objects, e.g.:

```
def foo(rdd: RDD[Seq[String]]) = { println("hi") }
```

This function cannot be called on objects of type RDD[Array[String]]:

```
val testRdd : RDD[Array[String]] = sc.textFile("somefile").map(_.split("\\|", -1))
foo(testRdd)

->
error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]
required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Seq[String]]
```

I guess that's because RDD isn't covariant.

I've tried a bunch of definitions of foo to get around this. Only one of them has compiled:

```
def foo2[T[String] <: Seq[String]](rdd: RDD[T[String]]) = { println("hi") }
```

But it's still broken:

```
foo2(testRdd)


->
<console>:101: error: inferred type arguments [Array] do not conform to method foo2's type
parameter bounds [T[String] <: Seq[String]]
          foo2(testRdd)
          ^
<console>:101: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]
required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T[String]]
```

Any idea how I can work around this? This is all taking place in the Spark shell.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your example why this definition of `foo` wouldn't be enough: `def foo[T](rdd: RDD[T])`. Also, note that there's **no subtyping relation between `Array` and `Seq`**. There's just an implicit conversion in `Predef` which allows us to use `Array` in places where `Seq` is required. Source: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.Array

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan `foo(new RDD(...)` would work, but `val rdd: RDD[Array[String]] = ...; foo(rdd)` will not. There does not exist a transform `RDD[Array[String]] => RDD[Seq[String]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this you can use a [view bound](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/130).

`Array` is not a `Seq`, but it can be *viewed* as a `Seq`.

```
def foo[T <% Seq[String]](rdd: RDD[T]) = ???
```

The `<%` says that `T` can be viewed as a `Seq[String]` so that whenever you use a `Seq[String]` method on `T` then `T` will be converted to `Seq[String]`.

For `Array[A]` to be viewed as `Seq[A]` there needs to be an implicit function in scope that can convert `Array`s to `Seq`s. As Ionuț G. Stan said, it exists in [scala.Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.Array).